# Hiding dropdown list when list is empty

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a dropdown list that is populated on page load and sometimes the dropdown list doesn't contain anything and is empty. I would like the hide the dropdown list whenever there aren't any items in the list. I thought i could do this via javascript but i am not sure what i could be doing wrong because after adding the javascript it stills appear on the page.

dropdown select:

```
<select data-bind="options: endReason() ? endReason().SubReasons : [], value: subReasonId, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', visible: isChecked"
                            name="subReasons">
                        </select>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function OnClientDropDownOpening(sender, eventArgs) 
{   var combo = $find("<%= subReasons %>"); 
    items = combo.get_items(); 
    if(items.get_count()==0) 
    { 
         eventArgs.set_cancel(true); 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the code appears to be leveraging knockoutjs

Answer (score 6):

Why javascript? Seems a complete waste of bandwidth when you could use a condition on the server side and not even render the ddl if there aren't any elements to render:

```
@if (Model.Items.Count() > 0)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemId, Model.Items)
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Just a side note: If you are not using Razor, the following basically does the same thing: <%: if (Model.Items.Count() > 0) { %> ...html here <%: } %>

Answer (score 0):

The following requires that you include the jQuery library.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {
    if ($('select[name=subReasons]').length == 0)
        $('select[name=subReasons]').remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Like I said, it requires the jQuery library to be included.

Also, yes it removes the DDL. He already stated it is populated on page load and he wants it gone if it doesn't contain any elements. So yes, I'm removing the DDL.

The more appropriate solution would be the one provided by Darin but only if he is using Razor for his views. Otherwise, he could include his HTML within
<%: if (Model.Items.Count() > 0) { %>
...html here
<%: } %>

Also there was no mention of Razor or the fact that the Model may not be an enumerable containing the elements used to populate this particular combo box.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job in pure JavaScript:

```
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var options = select.getElementsByTagName("option");
document.write('Select has ' + options.length + ' options');​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BZcW/)